# integral substitution question

Tags: calculus, integration

The question simply asks to show the equality is true

$$\int_{b+c}^{a+c}f(x-c)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Working on the left side, I substitute $u=x-c$  and  end up with 
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(u)du$$

So clearly $du=dx$ which allows me to make the substitution

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(u)dx$$

My question is that in the solution, they also replace $u$ with $x$ as follows

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Why can we also replace $u$ with $x$?

Comment: $u$ and $x$ are dummy variables.

Comment: $\int _{ a }^{ b } f(x)dx=\int _{ a }^{ b } f(u)du=\int _{ a }^{ b } f(t)dt=...$ they all are same,

Comment: "which allows me to make the substitution $\int_a^bf(u)\,dx$"????? No.

Comment: ah! thanks.  I thought that perhaps since I set $u=x-c$ then that might've changed things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy variable means

$$\int_a^bf (x)dx=\int_a^bf (t)dt $$
$$=\int_a^bf (u)du=\int_a^bf(v)dv $$
$$=\int_a^bf (\alpha)d\alpha=\int_a^bf $$

you can choose any letter other than $a $ and $b .$

Answer (score 1):

You already made the complete substitution $u = x-c$ in the first step. No need to re-replace $du$ by $dx$ again in the second step.

The complete calculation is
$$\int_{a+c}^{b+c} f(x-c) dx = \Big |\substack{x-c = u\\ dx = du }\Big| = \int_a^b f(u) du.$$

After the substitution, all $x$ are gone, and are replaced by the substituting variable, according to the rules.